# Consistent error in pulling / pushing from virtual GitHub repo already set up in VSC

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, github

Background TL;DR:

*I have been using PyCharm for Python as well as working directly on Jupyter NB, but recently I got interested in Manim, which seems to promote the use of Microsoft VSC because it has an extension to preview visualizations.
Unfortunately, I am stuck setting up my Git connection to my remote GitHub repository to back up some Python files that I am starting to generate in VSC.
It seems rather straightforward on the interface, but it is consistently spitting back errors, and frankly, my interest in an in-depth learning of VSC is restricted in time allocation, so if someone would be kind enough to just let me know what I am doing wrong, I would really appreciate it.*

I did initialize a repository by clicking going to

`View` -> `Command Palette` -> `Git: Initialize Repository` -> `SELECTED FOLDER FROM EXPLORER` -> `Would you like to open initialized repository? OPEN` -> `CLICKED ON SOURCE CONTROL` -> `SELECTED COMMIT AND PUSH FROM DOWN ARROW IN COMMIT:`

[image]

Got a message:

[image]

whereas in reality there are 27 files ready to commit.

I clicked `YES`.

Got this pop-up message:

[image]

`CLICKED ON Add Remote` -> `Pasted GitHub repo URL` -> `GAVE IT A NAME` -> `ENTER`

and got this message:

```
(upstream:remotename)%00%(upstream:remoteref) --ignore-case refs/heads/main [65ms]
2024-02-27 14:04:24.627 [info] > git config --local branch.main.vscode-merge-base [100ms]
2024-02-27 14:04:24.628 [warning] git config failed: Failed to execute git
2024-02-27 14:04:24.720 [info] > git reflog refs/heads/main --grep-reflog=branch: Created from *. [88ms]
2024-02-27 14:04:24.850 [info] > git symbolic-ref --short refs/remotes/origin/HEAD [122ms]
2024-02-27 14:04:24.851 [info] fatal: ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

---

Similarly, trying as follows:

I have committed and tried to push the files currently in the local folder in Windows. The files are not in the remote repository. So I tried clicking on:

[image]

which led to this error pop-up message:

[image]

and this on the command terminal:

[image]

If I try doing a `Pull`, here is the error I get:

[image]

I have a `.git` file in the Folder with this `config`:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
[remote "vsc_scripts"]
    url = https://github.com/MY_GITHUB_ACCOUNT_NAME/VSC_sc.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/vsc_sc/*
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked (this time):

1. Do not set up any remote GitHub repo.
2. Create or open a Windows folder. In this example the name is `IMAGINETHERESNOMSWINDOWS`
3. Open folder from within VSC:
4. Create documents if the folder is empty.
5. Select `Source Control` -> `Publish to GitHub`

[image]

6. An option to publish to a GitHub private repository with a name matching the folder will pop up at the top. Do not click! Instead, just ENTER.

[image]

7. The files in the folder will be selected by default.

[image]

8. Click OK. Hopefully, this is the end of the set-up.
9. Now if you create a new file, it will appear in green, and with a U for uncommitted:

[image]

10. Click on `Source Control`
11. Enter a message in the box (in this case `init`).
12. Click on the pull-down option `Commit & Push`. Some annoying message may still pop-up. Click `Yes` or just go for a walk to keep your cool.

[image]